# Block the single URL/Request that is taking too much time in multi_curl and continue with the remaining requests

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

How can we block/timeout a single request in multi_curl in PHP that is taking too much time while not affecting remaining requests

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to make some HTTP Requests where the response time can be unpredictable or too long to run consecutively and would like to run the request concurrently.

I do this when running W3C validation tools.
I do CSS validation,m HTML validation and XHTML validation. (I like my code to use as much as XHTML and only use HTML5 when necessary.  Old W3C mobile best practice habit.)

Before I transmit the stream_socket_client().

This is about as close to multi-tasking as PHP gets.

### Initialize variables.

$url is the fully qualified URL for the page under test e.g. http://example.com/index.html

```
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  $webPageTestKey = ' [key for WebPageTest.org goes here] ';
  $timeout = 120; 
  $result = array(); 
  $sockets = array(); 
  $buffer_size = 8192;
  $id = 0;
  $urls = array();
  $path = $url;
  $url = urlencode("$url");
```

### Make the Requests with stream_socket_client()

**The request urls are stored in the $urls[] array**

```
  $urls[] = array('host' => "jigsaw.w3.org",'path' => "/css-validator/validator?uri=$url&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=no&lang=en&output=text");
  $urls[] = array('host' => "validator.w3.org",'path' => "/check?uri=$url&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&output=json");
  $urls[] = array('host' => "validator.w3.org",'path' => "/check?uri=$url&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=XHTML+Basic+1.1&group=0&output=json");
  $urls[] = array('host' => "www.webpagetest.org",'path' => "/runtest.php?f=xml&bwDown=10000&bwUp=1500&latency=40&fvonly=1&k=$webPageTestKey&url=$url");
```

sockets need the host and path.
If you cannot easily see the format of the urls dump the array with

```
var_export($urls);
```

continued:

```
  $err = '';
  foreach($urls as $path){
    $host = $path['host'];
    $path = $path['path'];
    $http = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\n\r\n";
    $stream = stream_socket_client("$host:80", $errno,$errstr, 120,STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT); 
    if ($stream) {
      $sockets[] = $stream;  // supports multiple sockets
      $start[] = microtime(true);
      fwrite($stream, $http);
    }
    else { 
   $err .=  "$id Failed<br>\n";
    }
  }
```

The Request Sockets are stored in array $sockets[]

Then I transmit HTML while waiting for the requests to complete.**strong text**

### Retrieve Responses to Requests with  stream_select()

**Responses come back in the order in which they are received.  The order in which the requests were made does not matter.**

Responses are read in via an 8K buffer.  If the response is more than 8K multiple chunks are retrieved 8K at a time.

```
while (count($sockets)) {
  $read = $sockets; 
  stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, $timeout);
  if (count($read)) {
    foreach ($read as $r) { 
      $id = array_search($r, $sockets); 
      $data = fread($r, $buffer_size); 
      if (strlen($data) == 0) { 
     //   echo "$id Closed: " . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
        $closed[$id] = microtime(true);  // not necessary
        fclose($r); 
        unset($sockets[$id]);
      } 
      else {
        $result[$id] .= $data; 
      }
    }
  }
  else { 
 //   echo 'Timeout: ' . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
    break;
  }
}
```

The HTTP Responses are stored in the $result[] array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Your answer must be correct but in my case simply curl_setopt($curly[$id], curlopt_timeout_ms, 1000) worked. Iwas frustrated with initial tries but realized soon that I was using parameter curlopt_timeout instead of curlopt_timeout_ms and hence this was taking a lot of time. Now the requests that are taking a more than 1000MS/ 1sec are blocked without affecting the complete program

Comment: Yes that works but has limitations.  There will be a one second delay before the 1000mS timeout and curl completes vs. no delay.  You cannot get a HTTP response so the status of the request is unknown.  The socket connection curl made with the target will be closed.  When the connection is closed some apps will stop functioning.  For example if a PHP script is called the ignore_user_abort() must be set or the script will abort. Usually the reason for doing this is because the request takes too long and the called app may abort when curl times out.